# Why is molar density of solids and liquids taken as 1?

Tags: equilibrium

In the expression for equilibrium constant, the molar density values of solids and liquids are taken as 1. Is the active mass taken as the molar density of reaction divided by molar density at standard states? Then why do we take molar concentration for gases instead of molar concentration / standard molar concentration?

Comment: Search the site as it was answered before.

Comment: What is "molar density"? The term in the equilibrium constant is usually called the chemical or thermodynamic *activity* AFAIK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_activity